# Scaling gone a stray?

Tags: modeling

[image: Example of what I'm trying to scale.]

So I scaled the top part like so.

Now all of the sudden whenever I try to scale it does this.[image: Scaling is just moving it!?]

It seems like scaling it is just moving it now, also when I hit "S" to scale and then type in 0 it just shoots to the bottom of the mesh.

Please help me brothers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably your scale center is the 3D cursor.

Scaling and other operations are dependent to the center of it.

You can change that from the options shown in the picture below.

For what you want, probably "median point" is the good choice.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I knew it had to be something obvious. There must be a hotkey for it that I must have accidentally pressed?

Comment: Period key (.) and comma key (,) are the keys to change modes.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have your pivot center set to the 3d cursor? Press comma to set it to bounding box center.

Comment: Also, pressing zero after pressing "S" is telling blender to make that edge scale zero.

Comment: You're totally welcome!